# Range of dates as fetch predicate - NSDate predicate between Core Data

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, nspredicate

I am trying to fetch core data items stored in Core Data filtered to a range of dates under the field eventStartDate which is Date type - I am using managed object called Event generated by Xcode to proxy the core data item. When I execute the fetch request nothing is returned. I tried looking at the SQL logs and see that the follow sql is being called, which look correct:

```
SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK FROM ZEVENT t0 WHERE ( t0.ZEVENTSTARTDATE > ? AND  t0.ZEVENTSTARTDATE <= ?) ORDER BY t0.ZEVENTSTARTDATE
```

I get nothing back, when i try to po [mgtEventArray count] I get nil on the object.

my code for fetching:

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit ) fromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSDate *startDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
[components setMonth:10];
[components setDay:0]; 
[components setYear:0]; 
NSDate *endDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:startDate options:0];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"((eventStartDate > %@) AND (eventStartDate <= %@))",startDate,endDate];


NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Event" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:sortDescKey ascending:YES];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
[sortDescriptor release];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *mgtEventArray = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
if(error != nil)
    NSLog(@"%@", error);
return mgtEventArray;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks a lot like your like your variables `startDate` and `endDate` would contain unexpected values. The `startDate` is from date components without a day etc., and the `endDate` from the `startDate`.

Thus, I recommend putting breakpoints or `NSLog` statements before your predicate definition in order to check these values.

Also, it is not clear what `NSCalendar` you are using. From the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtCalendars.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003470):

> Day, week, weekday, month, and year numbers are generally 1-based, but
>   there may be calendar-specific exceptions.

So it seems that e.g. setting the `day` property to `0` might be problematic.

Answer (score 2):

Try a different format for your predicate:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(eventStartDate > %@) AND (eventStartDate <= %@)",startDate,endDate];`
```

Only put paratheses around the single statements, not around the whole statement.

Answer (score 0):

After iOS 6, as said before, this predicate works.

```
  NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"startDate > %@",[NSDate date];`
```

Thank you.